# How to set VS not to set .sln which version 2010 to 2012 automatically

Tags: c#

I got a Virual Studio project form a gitlab which version is 2010.My VS version is 2012 which always set it's .sln version to 2012 automatically.I have to reduction it before commit everytime.Is there a way to set VS not to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No way to do so unfortunately.